# How to boot linux in console mode

Tags: grub, efi

I've installed ubuntu 17.10 on HP Stream 7, EFI, x86. It loads and works fine. But I want to boot it in console mode.
I've edited `/etc/default/grub` commenting out `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"` and uncommenting `GRUB_TERMINAL=console`. Ran the `sudo update-grub` and after reboot I am still loaded to GUI. What else can I do?

Comment: I am unsure if Ubuntu 17.10 uses systemd or not.  If the answer is yes, then check here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264393/how-to-disable-x-server-autostart-in-debian-jessie

Comment: That actually helped. But now when I type letters at login, all those have control symbols before. For example, when I type `artur`, I get `^[a^[r^[t^[u^[r`. Of course I am not able to login with that =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [systemd documentation of Redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Targets.html#sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Targets-Change_Default) (systemd should be the same on Ubuntu) you could change the default target in systemd:

```
systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

The default target should be `graphical.target` and you can get that with this command:

```
systemctl get-default
```

**Edit:**
Just tested on a Linux Mint machine. Unfortunately after reboot the tty7 (where usually the Desktop is) tries to open. Then we can change with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to tty1. According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115540/223965 you could add `chvt 1` to `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: That actually helped. But now when I type letters at login, all those have control symbols before. For example, when I type `artur`, I get `^[a^[r^[t^[u^[r`. Of course I am not able to login with that =)

Comment: You have change the tty with ```CTRL+ALT+F1```. To set the default TTY, see my edit. I didn't test this part.

Comment: I am loaded to tt1 by default and this is where I get that strange input

Comment: and do you have a login prompt? What happening when you change with ```CTRL+ALT+F2``` to tty2? Does tty1-6 work when your default target is ```graphical.target```?

Comment: I am getting to the login prompt but now I cannot do anything. `CTRL + ALT + F2` does not work. And I cannot login to change configs to graphical.target. Somehow my keyboard inputs are overwritten with ^[ garbage

Comment: To get back to a working graphical.target you could try this:

1. Start with a Live CD oder USB
2. mount your system partition
3. Remove symlink <mountpath>/etc/systemd/system/default.target.
4. Create symlink from <mountpath>/etc/systemd/system/default.target to /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target.

Comment: The restoring actually worked. But I still don't know the reason why the escape symbol ^[ is inserted in front of each key press in console mode login and works perfectly fine in graphical mode.

Comment: Cool that the restore worked, I didn't want you to have an unusable computer ;-) If you are in graphical mode, what happens if you change to tty1 with ctrl+alt+F1? Do you have also this characters? Wild guess: input as utf16, so the first 8bits are escaped...

Comment: No worries regarding unusable computer. It is a tablet just for this purposes. No information on it, can be reflashed at any point with no harm. The CTRL + ALT + F2 actually worked. Looks like gui is running on tty1. Also in console mode on tty2 everything worked fine with inputs. No escapes there for as long as it was booted along with GUI manager.
Also when I installed Debian, the GUI did not work so the console mode was booted. And it had same escape problem.

Comment: Then you could try it again with ```chvt 2``` in ```/etc/rc.local``` after changing the default target.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65823/discussion-between-artur-korobeynyk-and-chloesoe).